# Continuous Bivariate Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Two continuous, independent random variables X and Y each take a random value uniformly distributed between 0 and 8. What is the probability that the difference between them is greater than 4?

Intuitively, I think it's 1/2, because it seems like for every case where the difference is greater than 4, there is a mirrored case where the difference is lesser than 4.

Any ideas on how to prove or am I just wrong?

Comment: There are various different probability distributions on the interval from $0$ to $8$.

Comment: There are various different dependence relationships beteween probability distributions on the interval from 0 to 8.

Comment: You probably want to write **are independent**.

Comment: To solve this, draw an $8\times8$ square: $0 \leq x \leq 8$ and  $0 \leq y \leq 8$.  Draw lines for $|x-y| = 4$.  Measure areas.

Answer (score 1):

For this, we know that $x\in\left[0,8\right]$ and $y\in\left[0,8\right]$, so we just need to have $\left|x-y\right|>4$. This only occurs if $x\in\left(4,8\right]$ and $y\in\left[0,4\right)$ or visa versa with $y\in\left(4,8\right]$ and $x\in\left[0,4\right)$.

Therefore.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X-Y\right|>4\right) &= \mathbb{P}\left(\left(X>4\cap Y<4\right)\cup\left(Y>4\cup X<4\right)\right) \\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(X>4\cap Y<4\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(Y>4\cup X<4\right)\quad\text{by additivity} \\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(X>4\right)\mathbb{P}\left(Y<4\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(Y>4\right)\mathbb{P}\left(X<4\right)\quad\text{by independence} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}